# SDL_CreateRenderer fails when compiled with software rendering only

Tags: rendering, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile a project ([tyr-quake](https://disenchant.net/tyrquake/)) with my custom build of SDL2. My SDL2 build among other things disables all accelerated video (OpenGL, OpenGLES, Vulkan, Metal, etc), X11 and Wayland, but enables KMSDRM.

All is well, and the project I wanted to compile with this build of SDL2 compiled too. Except that when running, `SDL_CreateRenderer` returns `Couldn't find matching render driver` (even if I modify the source to pass it `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` and set the `SDL_HINT_FRAMEBUFFER_ACCELERATION` hint to `"0"`).

I looked around the SDL source code a bit, and the software `SW_CreateRenderer` is indeed being called, but later on (in `SDL_CreateWindowTexture`) it still wants to create a renderer using a different render driver (it explicitly avoids the software one).

I also tried patching the source code to do the following:

```c
SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(sdl_window);
renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);
```

But that also failed, as `SDL_GetWindowSurface` fails with `No hardware accelerated renderers available` and returns NULL.

My question is: is there a way to **only** have software rendering with SDL when using KMSDRM, or am I required to have some hardware accelerated rendering option enabled and available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out on my own.

It is not possible to do so. But, if one wants to do that, implementing `CreateWindowFramebuffer`, `UpdateWindowFramebuffer` and `DestroyWindowFramebuffer`, and setting the appropriate function pointers should grant you the ability to create a purely software-based renderer. Sadly, I don't know KMS and DRM enough to be able to implement this myself.